# "Externalize" a column in a MySQL table

Tags: mysql, database, partition

i have kind of a weird request. My research up to this point and my previous experience tell me that it's not doable, but i want some more opininions.

I've been dropped in a flawed system, designed more than 10 years ago for a certain amount of data, and that has exploded in the last years.
I have a couple of tables in my DB that have a blob field containing an XML. Not so big, around 20-30k per xml, but i have a few millions rows in each table.

The problem is that the queries are quite slow, and the tables are quite big. I've checked and, without the xml field, each table will shrink more than 100x. Also this value is rarely read or written.

My question is this: the best practices would suggest to split the tables into t1_description and t1_contents - the first containing all the field except the xml and the latter containing just this one (and a fk) - but this system has a lot of applications reading and writing on the db, and a few of this application are huge monolith built with little to no future development in mind.
Changing the DB is out of the question, but: can i "externalize" the field, kinda like a partition would do, but without actually changing the table structure?

In this way any application requesting the xml field shouldn't need to change anything, but the DB would auto provide this data when requested.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You are using MyISAM, right? In that case, you could switch from varchar to a text/blob-datatype. In MyISAM, varchars are stored in row, and text-fields are stored off row. Text and varchar datatypes should be interchangeable, but you would of course have to check if your applications will properly work with that. InnoDB will store both types (partially) off row, so switching to InnoDB should be an alternative (although that would require some more testing).

Comment: Nope, already using InnoDB. I still have a few legacy systems with MyISAM, but every single one is already blob and not varchar,

Comment: In that case, you could add an index with all columns except the xml column. MySQL will/should use this index for every query that does not require the xml column and thus act as a smaller table.

Comment: That's a great suggestion! I will try it out and see how it works.